# weird behaviour while removing duplicates in list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list of integers.

What I would like to do is to sort them and remove all duplicates. 
I saw two different solutions on the internet. Both seem to give the same result which is not the one I expect.

```
a = integer_combinations(5, 5)
print a
>>[4, 8, 16, 32, 9, 27, 81, 243, 16, 64, 256, 1024, 25, 125, 625, 3125]

b = sorted(a)
print b
>>[4, 8, 9, 16, 16, 25, 27, 32, 64, 81, 125, 243, 256, 625, 1024, 3125]

c = dict().fromkeys(sorted(a)).keys()
print c
>> [32, 64, 4, 1024, 625, 8, 9, 256, 16, 81, 243, 3125, 25, 27, 125]
```

Another method, using sets:

```
d = list(set(b))
print d
>> [32, 64, 4, 1024, 625, 8, 9, 256, 16, 81, 243, 3125, 25, 27, 125]   

What I expect is :
>>[4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, 64, 81, 125, 243, 256, 625, 1024, 3125]
```

Would someone know the reason of this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I would use:

```
>>> a = [4, 8, 16, 32, 9, 27, 81, 243, 16, 64, 256, 1024, 25, 125, 625, 3125]
>>> sorted(set(a))
[4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, 64, 81, 125, 243, 256, 625, 1024, 3125]
```

The reason your code doesn't work as expected is that `dict` does not guarantee any particular ordering of its keys. Similarly, `set` has no guarantees as to the ordering of its elements.

Therefore, the sorting step has to come right at the end.

Comment: Actually, this is actually what I had done. . . the order of function calls reversed. Your way of doing it seem better.

Comment: Also consider using frozenset when you know it won't be mutable. In this case doesn't matter but allows you to hash, thus place in another set or dictionary if you are doing this for multiple integer combinations.

Comment: Thanks, I look at that. Lots of new vocabulary for me here :)

Answer (score 3):

`set()` is an unordered collection. Like dictionary it permutes keys on purpose for fast access. Therefore: `list(set(...))` returns list of unsorted items. Use instead:

```
sorted(set(...))
```

if you need ordered sequence.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Hmm, I should read the question more carefully. The answer is: set() is unordered collection. Like dictionary it permutes keys on purpose for fast access. Therefore: list(set(...)) returns list of unsorted items. Use instead: sorted(set(...)) if you need ordered sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Python `set` was introduced in version 2.3. Solution proposed by @aix is most Pythonic if you are using Python >=2.3

In your code, the following line ...

```
c = dict().fromkeys(sorted(a)).keys()
```

creates a `dict` with keys from `a` and values default to `None`. And then, just retrieves the keys using `keys()` method. Since dictionaries have no defined order, the elements are retrieved randomly. You need to resort them. In any case, you should really use `sorted(set(a))` as proposed already.

Comment: I don't see the point in using `sorted` anyway. If anything you would use sorted on the outside: c = sorted(dict().fromkeys(a).keys()) . There's no point in doing it the other way.

Comment: I agree. It seemed like OP arrived at a possible solution by doing a quick search on the internet ... " I saw two different solutions on the internet." And the solution he found was very dated. And he asked "Would someone know the reason of this behaviour?" So I was just trying to explain the behavior. As mentioned, `sorted(set(a))` is the right way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The `keys` method returns the keys of a dictionary in an undefined (yet consistent between calls) order, regardless of how the dictionary is created. [EDIT: as pointed out in the comment, the order is consistent as long as the dictionary remains unchanged.]

Comment: The order can change when keys are added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

dictionary doesn't guarantee iterating (and printing) keys in insertion order .

Use `collections.OrderedDict` for that.